# PowerBI Service Assign Workplace for different people

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am about to publish a PowerBI dashboard onto PowerBI Service to be shared across the company. Currently, the dashboard consists of 6 tabs.
There are 3 groups of people who will have access to it, but RLS is not applied since the access will be page level, rather than filter level. For example, sales people will only have access to sales related tabs, (2/6 tabs) while management will have full access to all 6 tabs.

That being said, I may need to create 3 different dashboards based on this need, which causes redundancy.

However, when I add people to workplaces, do i also need to create 3 workplaces and each of them will contain the specific dashboard for that group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page level security is not currently possible in Power BI. If you can't use RLS, I would do the following.(though I would recommend RLS) There would be some redundancy in this solution. You would have to maintain a Sales Version of the report, and a management version of the report).

1. Create Security groups for your different audiences. For example, Sales, and Management. You may need to work with IT or whomever is your Microsoft Admin. Your admin needs to put those people in their respective group.
2. Create a Power BI App with your reports in it.
3. When you publish the app, you can have two different audiences. The sales audience would have access to the Sales Report, and the management team would have access to the management report.

Here's a great blog about app audiences. https://data-goblins.com/power-bi/app-audiences

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. I tried to create different audience groups. Which was successful. However, when it comes to page restriction, I dont see any option to delete a particular page under a specific audience. Am I missing something? Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome Professor. We can't do page restriction in a report unless we use RLS. You will have to have a Sales Report (that has the fewer pages) , and a Managers Report that has all pages. In your app ,you will assign the sales report for the sales audience, and the managers report for the managers audience.

Comment: Hello Zach, just want to clarify one more thing. When it comes to different audience group, I thought the primary objective is to save storage/overhead/maintenance cost and effort. But if we need to upload separate reports for different audience groups within a single workplace. Is it different from having separate reports in separate workplaces ? Thank you.

Comment: It isn't terribly different and may make more sense in the long term to have a Sales workspace, and a Management workspace. Especially if you will have different reports for those groups. If you envision the two groups having reports in the future applicable to both groups, then it would be better to have the reports in the same workspace and guide the access by audiences and creating an app for that workspace.

Comment: Thank you Zach. I will go ahead and create separate workplaces for simplicity.